# How to set onkeyup event for input

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have GET request methods which called the maximum number of a product.

```
data() {
    return {
      itemMaxQty: ''
    }
  },

methods: {
   setMaxItem(event) {
       const value = event.target.value;
       console.log('value', value);
       if(value > this.maxItemQty) {
          value = this.maxItemQty
       } else if(value < 0) {
         value = 0
       }
   },

    maxItem(){

    let item_id = this.itemID;
                        
      axios.get("./available/" + item_id).then((response) => {
        console.log('maxItem', response.data); \\output: maxItem 9
        this.maxItemQty = response.data;
      })
    }
  }
```

How can I set the `onKeyUp` attributes so that when user enter quantity more than `maxItem`, the input value will auto change = `maxItem` value?

```
<input
  type="number"
  min="1"
  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
  name="quantity" 
  id="quantity" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="1" 
  value="1" 
  @keyUp="setMaxItem()"
>
```

Comment: why don't you set the `:max="maxItemQty"`

Comment: because I need to make sure that when user try to enter value more that `maxItemQty`, the value will automatically force change to max value @JuanEizmendi

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on @ZloiGoroh but i don't have enough points.

I don't see in the code `setMaxItem` returning a promise. And i don't think the idea is to make a api call on each key press to determin `itemMaxQty`. if so i would still not recommend to do that.

Since the question also has code to calculate the minumum value i would change the watcher implementation:

```js
inputedNumber(newValue) {
  if (newValue > this.maxItemQty) {
    this.inputedNumber = this.maxItemQty
  } else if (newValue < 0) {
    this.inputedNumber = 0;
  }
}
```

or to just clamp the values with [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```js
watch: {
  inputedNumber(newValue) {
    /* 
      Math.max -> returns the highest of the two
      Math.min -> returns the lowest of the two
      the lowest number allowed is 0
      the heighest number is either the newValue 
      or if that value is heigher than maxItemQty maxItemQty itself
    */

    this.inputedNumber = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.maxItemQty)
  }
}
```

Some might argue about the `inputedNumber` always being updated even if the value is between the min and max, but the performance loss in this cause is neglect-able of not zero.

Even though the question was on keypress i would not go that route in your case.

ps. My only intention was to provide a minimal solution and not go into naming and/or refactoring the answer to best practises

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try this code

```
<input
  type="number"
  min="1"
  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
  name="quantity" 
  id="quantity" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="1" 
  value="1" 
  onkeyup="setMaxItem()"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a watcher, first of all you need to make a v-model it will bind input elemnt value and reactive vue data

```
<input
    type="number"
    min="1"
    name="quantity" 
    id="quantity" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="1"
    v-model="inputedNumber"
>
```

Then create same property in data

```
data() {
    return {
        itemMaxQty: '',
        inputedNumber: 1,
    }
},
```

And now we can make a watcher

```
watch: {
    inputedNumber(newValue) {
        this.setMaxItem().then(() => {
            if (newValue > this.maxItemQty) {
                this.inputedNumber = this.maxItemQty
            }
        })
    }
}
```